# Load different templates in ng-repeat like ui router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to load different templates in ng-repeat using ng-include directive.
Here's the code that I'm using.

HTML:

```
<li data-ng-repeat="list in checklist">
  <a href="" class="label-default" ng-click="loadTemplate(list.name)">{{list.name}}</a>
  <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>

  <div ng-if="list.name==listId">
    <div data-ng-include src="'heckList/profile1.html'"></div>
  </div>
</li>
```

and controller:

```
$scope.checklist = [
            { "id": 1, "name": "Add Profile" },
            { "id": 2, "name": "Add Marks" },
            { "id": 3, "name": "Add Records" }
        ];
$scope.loadTemplate=(name) => {
  $scope.listId = name;
}
```

Here I'm loading the same template on each click of a **href**.
But if I have multiple templates I want to load them based on each different conditions separately. How can I achieve it?

Comment: How big are these 'templates' you're wanting to load? Like one HTML tag?
You mean you just want to change the src attribute of the data-ng-include div based on the list object?

Comment: Can't you add Url into checklist and load it in your ng-repeat like list.url?

Comment: Is it possible to do without adding the template name in the controller..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work?

```
<li data-ng-repeat="list in checklist">
  <a href="" class="label-default" ng-click="loadTemplate(list.name)">{{list.name}}</a>
  <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>

  <div ng-if="list.name==listId">
    <div data-ng-include src="list.template"></div>

  </div>
</li>
```

```
$scope.checklist = [
  { "id": 1, "template": "template1", "name": "Add Profile" },
  { "id": 2, "template": "template2", "name": "Add Marks" },
  { "id": 3, "template": "template3", "name": "Add Records" }
];
```

$scope.loadTemplate=(name) => {
    $scope.listId = name;
  }